# Configuration to run two domains built with nuxtjs from sites-available default file nginx ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, nuxt.js

I want to run two domains on single digital ocean server. I have created two folders var/www/domain1/html and var/www/domain2/html and cloned my projects inside these olders. Installed pacagers, ran build and ran pm2, everything works fine. But when I open the domain address it shows "bad gateway". So, this error is because of the nginx sites-available configuration. Here is the sites-available default file:

```
`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain1.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain2.com;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}`
```

Both domains are running on the seperate ports so port is not an issue.

I'm facing 502 bad gateway error from nginx. I'm expecting that the issue is with nginx configuration inside /etc/nginx/sites-available and default file.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. In my case, I was listening on port 80 as you do but my website is using HTTPS.

---

So It can be an issue with your SSL if you are using HTTPS... then it should be listening on port 443 not 80 also check if the pm2 is running fine. You don't need to specify any path like /var/www/... as it is using the proxy pass.

---

The second possible reason can be a permission issue. So, handling permission correctly or using a docker image to deploy your application would be better.